# how to get last 100 tweets from a list using twitter4j

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I want to get last 100 tweets, but it seems that twitter4j api returns the fist 100 tweets if I give page number 1.

So, how do I reach to last 100?

Answer (score 5):

Its not possible without paging.

As mentioned here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline , paging occurs in one way only, that is tweets can be retrieved from `latest to older` , so the newer tweets will come in first page and then the older ones will come in later pages.

Since the limit is 200, you can get:

```
getUserTimeline(new Paging(1, 200));
```

If after, parsing the response, number of tweets are exactly 200 , then , you have to go the next page:

```
getUserTimeline(new Paging(2, 200));
```

... and so on, till the number of tweets retrieved are less than 200.

For Retrieving tweets from a specific list:

```
getUserListStatuses(LIST_ID,new Paging(1,200));
```

Comment: I don't want to get tweets from a user timeline, I want tweets from a list

Comment: @gurvinder372 you want tweets from user's lists?? or any particular list??

Comment: I want it from a specific list

Comment: This is returning data from oldest to latest..it returns first 200 tweets of the list members